# get multiple json objects from single controller call

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

How can I get multiple json objects from single MVC controller? In below example if I only want to return fishes (pond) I would do:

`return Json(pond, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

but how to return both fishes and trees in single json?

```
   public ActionResult PondAndForestData()
    {
        List<Fish> pond = context.getAllFishes();
        List<Tree> forest = context.getAllTrees();
        // return both as one combined Json?
    }
```

Comment: You can return array in one JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new anonymous object with 2 properties

```
public ActionResult PondAndForestData()
{
    List<Fish> pond = context.getAllFishes();
    List<Tree> forest = context.getAllTrees();
    return Json(new { Ponds= pond, Trees= forest},JsonRequestBehaviour.Allow.GET);
}
```

In your client side whereever you are calling this action method, you should access `Ponds` / `Trees` property as needed.Both of them will be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class containing the following as member variables. Then pass an instance of that class as JSON.

```
List<Fish> pond = context.getAllFishes();
List<Tree> forest = context.getAllTrees();
```